# Issue with bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am loading content into bootstrap modal from external url (Ajax) . So for me when  ever user click on the link, modal should open with latest data. But when I open modal first time it is loading content . But after closing and reopen again it is showing previous content only. Second time it is not communicating with external url. So for this I have replaced line at 1206 with this line of code in bootstrap.js (tried in version 3.3.5).

```
//if (!data) $this.data('bs.modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
New Line
if (!data || options.refresh) $this.data('modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
```

This is working fine, when I open and close modal and again open always it is fetching content via external url.
Now the issue is , In that modal I have some textfields with some general validations. For this I have used bootbox. Now when ever field is empty bootbox.alert() is firing, `but when I click on Ok button it is not closing`. 
And after submitting data from  modal , modal is also not closing. Even I have used this in Ajax success response `jQuery('#listmodal_popup').modal('hide');`

But when I comment this line from bootstrap.js and uncomment previous one this working fine with closing modal after submit and closing bootbox.alert.

```
if (!data || options.refresh) $this.data('modal', (data = new Modal(this, options)))
```

So how to solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix that I have found.

```
jQuery('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  jQuery(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

This is working for me, every time when I click on the link, it is communicating with external url and fetching latest data.

Answer (score 0):

It's never a good idea to alter the framework's code - a year later you will do an update and you will forget about this and things will start breaking. I know, this is not the case, but for future reference :)

Add this as the first thing after DOM ready

`$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
})`

This will disable caching of **all** AJAX requests done through jQuery, from now on. 
If this is an issue, you should disable caching only when opening the modal and enabling it back afterwards.